# Is it more efficient to use one function instead of multiple autocommands?

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, performance

I have a lot of lines with with filetype-specific autocommands defining mappings and abbreviations, which looks like this:

```
augroup vimrc
au!
...
au FileType blah nnoremap <buffer> aa bb
au FileType blah nnoremap <buffer> cc dd
au FileType blah inoreabbrev <buffer> www xxx
au FileType blah inoreabbrev <buffer> zzz yyy
...
augroup END
```

Etc..

I'm wondering if it would be more efficient to assign one function for each file type, and declare all mappings/abbrevs there. I'm asking purely from performance standpoint, not code style.

Comment: Potential answer writers: please do not speculate! Performance comparisons should be done with actual data. See also [questions to clarify when talking about performance](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: `<buffer>` should be written after the mapping and abbreviation commands, not before.
If performance is a concern, the best thing to do is to move all the mappings/abbreviations in a filetype plugin. See: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/wiki/where_to_put_filetype_specific_stuff#wiki_in_a_proper_filetype_plugin

Comment: There is already one autocmd which sources the filetype plugins: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/1614a14901558ca091329315d14a7d5e1b53aa47/runtime/ftplugin.vim#L31
This single autocmd is more efficient than several ad hoc filetype autocmds in the vimrc, simply because for all the settings to be sourced, the filetype needs to be checked only once, whereas with several autocmds it needs to be checked again and again for no good reason.
If a filetype plugin is not possible because you need to keep all your config in a single file, then use a function to avoid the repetition of filetype checks.

Comment: @user938271 I'd upvote that as an answer.

Comment: `purely from performance standpoint` No difference at all.

Comment: @user938271 Filetype plugin makes much sense and, of course, should be recommended. But it's only profitable if _there's no FileType blah_ opened in the current session. Otherwise, it's a bit slower (an additional file read operation).

Comment: @Matt I think you're right. A file read seems slower than a filetype check.

Comment: `purely from performance standpoint`: Does that really make sense here? What I mean is that in the context of your editor the performance only matters if you can see a difference when you use it and no matter how you do it I think it is very unlikely that you can actually feel the difference. So I don't think this is something you should think too much about.

Comment: @user938271 sounds like speculation to me—I’d like to see some hard numbers that we care about (@statox makes a great point, and asks one of the questions in the link I referenced).